# Is derivative of a continuously differentiable function on an open set always integrable?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $\varphi: [0,1)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\varphi(0)=0$, $\varphi$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ with $\varphi'>0$ and being nonincreasing on $(0,1)$. My question is:

Whether the function $\varphi'$ is integrable on $(0,1),$ or equivalently, can we write
$$\varphi(x)=\int_0^x \varphi'(t)dt \text{ for all } x\in(0,1)?$$

Here the integrand can be understood in the sense of Lebesgue or Riemann. I tried to search some posts about the integrability of the derivative of a continuously differentiable function but still cannot verify the question above.

Edit: Sorry for the mistake it should be $\varphi'$ is nonincreasing on $(0,1)$, not increasing.

Comment: $\varphi$ is continuous, therefor integrable on $[a,1)$ for any $a>0$. Also, $\varphi (x)=\varphi(a)+\int_a^{x} \varphi (t) dt$. Letting $a \to 0$ proves integability and validity of your formula.

Comment: Also, when you say "equivalently", this is not the meaning of "integrable on $(0,1)$."  $\phi'$ need NOT be integrable on $(0,1)$ - this would mean the integral converges for the whole interval.  $\phi'$ is LOCALLY integrable over $(0,1)$.  It is integrable over $[0,x)$ for $x<1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I think you meant "locally" as well here?

Comment: @MW $\int_0^{x} \varphi (t)dt$ exists both as a Lebesgue integral and as an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: @geetha290krm right, so actually i think maybe you meant "integrable on $[a,x)$" then? (and therefore integrable on $(0,x)$ for $x<1$) Usually "integrable" implies finite, is all I meant, so it wouldn't be "integrable on $[a,1)$ (or $(0,1)$).

Comment: It is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,x)$.  Remember that $\varphi'$ is positive and you get a  finite limit for the integral when you let $a \to 0$. @MW

Comment: @geetha290krm we might be talking around each other, I was only concerned with your original comment that it's integrable on $[a,1)$, which its not (integral can blow up as $x\to 1$).  I understand everything stays finite when $a\to 0$.

Comment: You are right. OP's formula holds for every $x<1$ (as desired by OP) and integrability holds on $(0,x)$ but integrability over $(0,1)$  is not guaranteed.  @MW

Comment: I made a mistake when posting. The derivative is nonincreasing. IDK if this affects your discussion or not. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example: $\varphi (x)=-\ln (1-x)$. If you just want integrability on $(0,x)$ for every $x<1$ and your formula to hold, then the answer is YES, as already pointed out in the comments above.
Thanks to MW for pointing out that integrability near $1$ is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, the integrability on $(0,x)$ for $x<1$ is fine with me. However, I still not clearly see how it works. \\

1. In your original comment, does the formula $\varphi(x)=\varphi(a)+\int_a^x \varphi(t) dt$ comes from the fundamental theorem of calculus?\\

2. How can we let $a\rightarrow 0$ in the equality above? It is clear that $\varphi$ is continuous, but why the integration function is continuous?\\

3. And how to prove the integrability of function $\varphi$ on $(0,x)$, i. e. the integral on this set is finite?

Btw, thanks a lot for your and MW's help.

Comment: 1. YES 2. Monotone Convergence Theorem. 3. LHS tends to a finite limit, so RHS must also be finite.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks a lot for your detailed comments.